# Generate all urls with https

Tags: plugins, ssl, https

I just got my website a ssl and i was making sure there aren't any mixed contents. But looks like everything else is working good except a form generated by plugin (The Newletter Plugin), that uses `home_url` in a lot of places. The url generated is http only even though my urls in general settings are https.

So, i was wondering that is there a **global way to force that all urls generated through wordpress functions generate secure link**?

I know `force_ssl_admin` for admin part and i know you can use `home_url('/','https')` and change all links that way. But i dont want to change the plugin everytime i update.

Or if i may missing something completely, please let me know. 
Thanks

Comment: Just curious, what is your settings on wp-admin setting panel (clicking on Settings -> General) for WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL)? and what type of content that have http? are those past-generated content or new content?

Comment: Both the site url and the wordpress url are in https

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a bug in the plugin, and they should fix it. But if they don't, you can always add a filter to `home_url` and change all http:// to https:// like so:

```
add_filter( 'home_url', 'wpse_259675_home_url', 1000, 4 );
function wpse_259675_home_url( $url, $path, $orig_scheme, $blog_id ) {
  return str_replace( 'http://', 'https://', $url );
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it is a bug. But the plugin definitely hasnt implemented anything to check if i am using it in a https website. It simply replied on home_url('\') to generate the links for the forms. Also I added your code, but it doesnt seem to help my cause! Thanks though

Comment: The code above simply replaces all occurrences of of http:// with https:// that is output by the home_url() and get_home_url() functions. If it's not changing anything, then the non-https links are probably not being generated by home_url().